# Cant import graphiz libraries - conda env

Tags: python, conda, python-import

I have installed the library in Base conda environment (the only one I have):

```
(base) C:\Users\44444>conda install graphviz
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Set the path in System -> Environment Variables : to both locations : where conda and where python

```
PATHs: 
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\Scripts\
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\
```

and when I try to import the library I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphviz'
```

Am I missing something please? How to import the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only installed the `graphiz` software, not the python interface to it. For that you will need [this package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-graphviz) which you can install with

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't add conda's folders to the system PATH manually. What you need to do to work with Anaconda is activating the environment via

```
conda activate
```

This will add all the following folders temporarily to the PATH:

```
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\44444\anaconda3\bin
```